# Another proof check on a real analysis problem(more intuition based as i dont know lot machinery)

Tags: real-analysis

I have been reading Terence Tao's book (Analysis I) for probably more than a week now and i am in section IX, where the first problem in the exercise is

Problem : Let $X \subset R$, and let $\overline{X}$ denote the closure of $X$. If $\exists$ a set $Y$ such that $X \subseteq Y \subseteq \overline{X}$. Prove that $\overline{Y}=\overline{X}$.

I know from the text that any subset of $\mathbb R$ is the union of limit points and isolated points. But the proof is not yet given. Intuitively, i thought of a proof like this,is this works?

Proof : Let $X=[\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}(a_1,b_i)]\cup[\bigcup_{i=1}^{S} A_i] \subseteq Y$

Thus $Y \subseteq \overline{X}=[\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}[a_1,b_i]]\cup[\bigcup_{i=1}^{S} A_i]$, hence

$Y/X \subseteq [\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}\{a_i \}]\cup [\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}\{b_i \}]$ and the conclusion follows.

Is this okay or more rigority is required?
(The proof of the fact that every such subset is union of limit and isolated points is not yet given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to say is that you need to define your notation. It's not clear to me what $a_i$, $b_i$, and $A_i$ are.

In particular, there are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which cannot be decomposed into finitely many intervals as you have written. Check $\mathbb{R}$ itself!

Your idea is along the right lines, but you need to generalise it a bit. Start from the definition of the closure. What do you need to show in order to show that  $\bar{Y} = \bar{X}$?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right!

Comment: We need to show that all the limit points are same and the isolated ones are contained within one another? I am new so i need a hint can you post a proof please, then i will understand the method of these type of proofs :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just now solved this using the fact that Closure is closed i.e, $\overline{\overline{X}}=\overline{X}$.

As $X \subseteq Y \subseteq \overline{X}$ thus, $\overline{X} \subseteq \overline{Y}$ and again, $\overline{Y}\subseteq \overline{\overline{X}}=\overline{X}$ thus $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}$ as desired.